# Python comparing integers and using if

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

```
Q = int(input("Enter a number."))
if Q > 30 and =< 40:
    import easygui
    easygui.msgbox("This number is greater than 30 and less than or equal to 40")
```

I don't know what's wrong it just says `"Invalid Syntax"` and highlights the equal sign in equal to or less than `40` before even running the code. `easygui` isn't the problem.

Comment: `and =< 40` and *what* is smaller or equal to `40`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably meant to do this:

```
#             v mention `Q` here
if Q > 30 and Q <= 40:
#               ^ i.e. `<` before `=`
```

Comment: Have you also changed `=<` to `<=`? The first option is not correct in python.

Comment: If you changed both, the syntax is then correct normally.

Comment: And actually, Python allows the very nice construct `30 < Q <= 40`

Comment: OK that worked, I guess I hadn't changed it back to <= since I was fiddling with it to try and fix it.

Comment: why `if Q > 30 and Q < 40:` it only work if i add `=` ?